# Are there nontrivial differentiable semimartingales? Or is there another sensible way to differentiate a Langevin-type equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $S_t$ be a continuos semimartingale, that is we have a decomposition
$$S_t = A_t + M_t + C,$$

where $A$ is of finite variation and $M_t$ is a local martingale.

Ito calculus allows us to make sense of the stochastic integral $ \int_0^T X_s dS_s$ in this situation. Now, when one considers the Langevin-type stochastic differential equation

$$ dX_t = f(X_t) dt + d S_t$$

this means that we have

$$ X_t = X_0 \int_0^t f(X_s) ds + \int_0^T dS_s = X_0 + \int_0^t f(X_s) ds + S_t.$$

I was wondering if one can in any sense get a higher-order differential equation from this. If $S_s$ was differentiable, then one would get
$$ \overset{\cdot}{X_t} = f(X_t)  + \frac{d}{dt} S_t$$

which would be equialent to the new SDE

$$ d \overset{\cdot}{X_t} = d f(X_t) + d \frac{d}{dt} S_t.$$

However, it is a common exercise to show that Brownian motion is not differentiable, which excludes the most common cases. Of course, if one chooses the local martingale to be zero ($M_t=0$), then one can just choose $A_t$ to be differentiable and this would work, but then essentially obtain an ODE. So, my question would be if there is anything in between, i.e. a semimartingale which has some local martingale contribution and is differentiable?

And if this does not exist, is there any other way to make sense of the differentiation of the original SDE to obtain equations of higher order?

Comment: Basically you are asking [if there exists a differentiable martingale](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397639/does-there-exist-an-almost-surely-differentiable-martingale) $M_t$ that is non zero. The given answer there says no.

Comment: BM is not differentiable in the classical sense. Yet you can define, say $\xi_{t}:=\frac{d}{dt}B_{t}$ in a distributional sense. What you get is white noise. However, if you have a process $X_{t}$ which is driven by a derivative of white noise, it's going to have very low regularity. In particular pointwise expressions like $f(X_{t})$ will typically not be well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments the main issues are

- Brownian motion is not differentiable
- generally any martingale that is differentiable is actually constant [Does there exist an almost surely differentiable martingale?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397639/does-there-exist-an-almost-surely-differentiable-martingale)

> Indeed, if a martingale is a.s. everywhere differentiable, then its quadratic variation is a.s $0$. So, by the Burkholder--Davis--Gundy inequality, the martingale is a.s. constant.